# Use table content in hyperlink jQuery

Tags: jquery

As shown in the image below, I have a table with product numbers and more. I would like the link behind the "PDF" button to automatically use the product number and .pdf at the end, so I won't have to do this manually.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" +/getfile +/productnumber +.pdf">
```

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

My HTML

```
<td>56900</td>
<td>76 mm</td>
<td>800 mm</td>
<td>2,6 mm</td>
<td>Fundament Serie A 800 mm</td>
<td style="width: 16px; height: 24px;"><a class="btn-green" href="/getfile/56900.pdf">PDF</a></td>
```

As I have no idea on how to, I have no JS code unfortunately.

[image: Table I need help with]

Comment: `Is there an easy way of achieving this?` Yes. You can use JS to loop over the rows of the table and amend the HTML of the PDF link. If you want a demonstration of how this is done, please edit your HTML and current JS attempt to solve this in to the question.

Comment: How do you create the table in the first place? Presumably you place the correct product number and other data into each table row somehow? At that same moment you can inject the product number into your hyperlink as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no need to loop even - the link can be created on click of the container

Comment: @ADyson That's correct, but instead of having to type everything, and copy and paste, I'd like to have this done automatically if the product number is typed in once. If we change product numbers, I have to go through every hyperlink as well.

Comment: @JeffreyvandenBogaart Why would you have to do anything manually? Don't you use some code to create your table already each time your page is loaded? Or are you saying this is some existing static HTML document which you want to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see why you cannot just have the table generated

Here is if you handcode the table

```js
$("table a").on("click", function(e) {
  this.href="/getfile/"+
    $(this).closest("tr").children().eq(0).text() + // first cell content
    ".pdf";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>56900</td>
    <td>76 mm</td>
    <td>800 mm</td>
    <td>2,6 mm</td>
    <td>Fundament Serie A 800 mm</td>
    <td style="width: 16px; height: 24px;"><a class="btn-green" href="">PDF</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>57000</td>
    <td>76 mm</td>
    <td>800 mm</td>
    <td>2,6 mm</td>
    <td>Fundament Serie A 800 mm</td>
    <td style="width: 16px; height: 24px;"><a class="btn-green" href="">PDF</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a likely more useful solution for you:

```js
var tableContent = [
  {
    id: 56900,
    dim1: 76,
    dim2: 800,
    dim3: 2.6, // note the dot
    fun: "Fundament Serie A 800 mm" // no trailing comma
  },
  {
    id: 57000,
    dim1: 80,
    dim2: 900,
    dim3: 2.9, // note the dot
    fun: "Fundament Serie B 900 mm"
  } // no trailing comma
];

var $tb = $("#tb_1"); // the tbody
$.each(tableContent,function(_,row) {
  $tb.append(
    $("<tr>"+
        "<td>"+row.id+"</td>"+
        "<td class='val'>"+row.dim1+"</td>"+
        "<td class='val'>"+row.dim2+"</td>"+
        "<td class='val'>"+String(row.dim3).replace(".",",")+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+row.fun+"</td>"+
        "<td><a class='btn-green' href='/getcontent/"+row.id+".pdf'>"+row.id+".pdf</td>"+
      "</tr>"  
    )
  );  
})
```

```css
.val { text-align: right;}

td { padding: 15px 20px; }


.btn-green {
  text-decoration:none;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 background: green;
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: solid 1px #20538D;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
}
.btn-green:hover {
 background: light-green;
 border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-green:active {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 background: teal;
 border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>dim1 mm</th>
    <th>dim2 mm</th>
    <th>dim3 mm</th>
    <th>Fundament</th>
    <th>PDF</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tb_1"></tbody>
</table>
```